# How to autoselect new added files when committing via tortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Lately, whenever I commit via tortoiseSVN, it only has modified/deleted files as 'selected', and all newly added files/folders have to be selected manually one by one. Is this a bug? How can I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how SVN and TortoiseSVN and I think any proper VCS works. You have to add the files explicitly. Though you can add a directory to add all files in it and in TortoiseSVN you can multi-select and add.

Comment: Fair enough, didn't know that they had to be added by right clicking the folder and doing add.